# How to convert an ArrayList to a final String array?

Tags: java, android

I need to convert an ArrayList to a String array which is declared as final,

I ended up with this:

```
        //new array
        String[] arrTextRow=new String[customListTxt.size()];
        customListTxt.toArray(arrTextRow);
        //new final array 
        final String[] arrTextRow2=arrTextRow;
```

it's working, but just wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve this, such as:

```
        final String[] arrTextRow =new String[]{
            for(String zz : customListTxt){
                //dosomethinghere
            }
        };
```

Comment: Why not just declare `arrTextRow` final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the one liner:

```
final String[] arrTextRow2=customListTxt.toArray(new String[0]);
```

The new String[0] is not that expensive, but you can always make it a constant.

Comment: Thanks! also previous solutions are fine, but this is the one I prefer

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the first Array `arrTextRow` final too.

```
//Convert to string array
final String[] arrTextRow = customListTxt.toArray(new String[customListTxt.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.toArray()`

```
final String[] array = customListTxt.toArray(new String[customListTxt.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way more elegant than `toArray()`. Also, you can define `arrTextRow` as `final`.

```
final String[] arrTextRow = new String[customListTxt.size()];
```

The point is, `final` doesn't make array element immutable, but the array reference itself, i.e., after defining the array as final, you cannot change the `arrTextRow`, but still can change the individual elements of it.

See [here for example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/final-arrays-in-java/)